# How can I connect stripe and calendly to save database records?

Tags: next.js, stripe-payments, calendly

I’m planning on abuilding a nextjs app and connecting it to a DB. I’d like users to login to their profiles where a summary of their calendly charged sessions through stripe is visible in a table format.

What would be the best way to get this done? I know both stripe and calendly have their own APIs to pull the data in but how can I connect them to save records in DB for a user with a unique email and ID?

Comment: You'll likely need to be more specific in order to get clear pointers here. What have you tried, and why doesn't that work? Possibly you want a webhook endpoint or a redirect landing page for Calendly to notify you of a booking, then initiate a payment as a result. Any more detail would need some clarity on your requirements and issues.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is too general. I think this is due to a lack of information about Stripe's features. To narrow down the problem, I'd recommend to start from [Usage-based pricing](https://stripe.com/docs/products-prices/pricing-models#usage-based-pricing). This will allow you to understand what data structure you will have in Stripe and what part of it you want to store in your database. So, in general you should pass session time from Calendly to Stripe. I don't know how it is in Calendly, but for Stripe, an email is not a unique identifier. Thus, ensuring uniqueness is up to you.